# how to avoid uploading file that is being partially written - Google storage rsync

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync

I'm using google cloud storage with option rsync
I create a cronjob that sync file every minute.
But there're the problem
Right on a file is being partially written, the cronjob run, then it sync a part of file even though it wasn't done. 
Is there the way to settle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The gsutil rsync command doesn't have any way to check that a file is still being written. You will need to coordinate your writing and rsync'ing jobs such that they operate on disjoint parts of the file tree. For example, you could arrange your writing job to write to directory A while your rsync job rsyncs from directory B, and then switch pointers so your writing job writes to directory B while your rsync job writes to directory A. Another option would be to set up a staging area into which you copy all the files that have been written before running your rsync job. If you put it on the same file system as where they were written you could use hard links so the link operation works quickly (without byte copying).